# How do I rename the Column Name on Acumatica Customers screen?

Tags: gridview, erp, acumatica

How do I rename the Column Name on Acumatica Customers screen?

I tried the below method on other screens, but for the customers page, it does not seem to be working:

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<PX.Objects.CR.CRRelation.BAccount__AcctName>(this.Transactions.Cache, "Customer Name");
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which Customers screen are you referring but AR.30.30.00 does not have view called Transactions out of the box.  Also, SetDisplayName in your case should take 3 parameters -

PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName(PXCahce, fieldname, displayName)

And changing display names for grid columns are best handled at DAC attribute level. At runtime, there is lesser know (read undocumented) repaintcolumns property that forces redraw of column headers which might work.

best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<DAC.field>(this.Transactions.Cache, null, "Field Name")
```

I don't have VS here so I don't remember the syntax correctly, hope it'll help